# SQL Server 2014 Stored Procedure Cache become full

Tags: sql, sql-server, caching, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have SQL Server 2014 and I have a stored procedure which fill out its cache. I have to clear the cache with `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` every third day, otherwise the stored procedure runtime grows from 8 seconds to 5 minutes.

We checked the stored procedure code but we have **not found** any point where could be the "parameter sniffing" happening.

We compared the plans from the cache but every plans are the same, so its look like the server could not reuse the cached plans and every time compile a new one.

We have several customers with the same DB, but only 1 reported this issue, the other servers at other customers are working fine.

Are there any SQL Server settings which could be cause this problem?

Somebody has any tips what could be wrong in the DB for example bad indexing or something like this?

Comment: Without a lot more details this is impossible to answer. Where is the procedure code, table definitions, indexes, etc...? How about an execution plan from the server where it goes bad?

Comment: This is very broad and you could have problems at many levels. Can you elaborate on what you mean by *fills out ti's cache*? The cache doesn't become full and stays full. SQL Server will clear things out as it needs memory. Your proc could just start using a new plan that isn't optimal, it could still have parameter sniffing, it could have ____________ where this is long list of things. Clearing out the cache would make it get a NEW plan and if this makes it faster then it was probably using a BAD / poor performing plan.

Comment: How many plans do you have in cache for the same proc?